# Comparing static field pointers at compile time

Tags: c++, static-assert

I have a class B deriving from class A.  A declares a static field f, and B might declare a similar field of the same name.  The following does not work:

```
struct A { static int f; };
struct B : A { static int f; }; // A::f is different from B::f
struct C : A {}; // A::f is the same as C::f
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((&A::f != &B::f));
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((&A::f == &C::f));
```

Even though theoretically those assertions could be checked at compile time, they are disallowed since constant expressions cannot take addresses.

Is there a way to make this kind of check work at compile time?

Comment: The address of an object with static storage duration is a constant expression.

Comment: @GManNickG: If the definitions of the static variables are not ahead of the static assert in the TU, GCC complains that it isn't a constant expression.  If they are, it works.  Not sure if this is justified by the standard.

Comment: @user1131467: Hm, all I can get out of the standard is §5.19/4: "An address constant expression is a prvalue core constant expression (after conversions as required by the context) of type std::nullptr_t or of pointer type that evaluates to the address of an object with static storage duration, to the address of a function, or to a null pointer value. Collectively, literal constant expressions, reference constant expressions, and address constant expressions are called constant expressions." Can't see anything about why the TU matters, hm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting the definitions of the static variables in scope of the static asserts.

This works fine with gcc 4.7.2:

```
struct A { static int f; };
struct B : A { static int f; };
struct C : A {};

int A::f;
int B::f;

static_assert(&A::f != &B::f, "B");
static_assert(&A::f == &C::f, "C");

int main()
{
}
```

Compile with:

```
$ g++ -std=gnu++11 test.cpp
$ ./a.out
```

Comment: Yeah, this is likely the best one can do.  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case, since I need the declarations to occur in a .cpp file elsewhere.